# Calling AS/400 RPG Programs from Java

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, rpg

I want to call AS/400 RPG Programs from java, but I'm facing an error as below

> com.ibm.as400.data.PcmlException: Exception received: [com.ibm.as400.access.ObjectDoesNotExistException] /QSYS.LIB/%LIBL%.LIB/GETKURSJAV.PGM: Object does not exist.
>                   at com.ibm.as400.data.ProgramCallDocument.callProgram(ProgramCallDocument.java:458)
>                   at CallRPG.main(CallRPG.java:34)
>   Caused by: com.ibm.as400.access.ObjectDoesNotExistException: /QSYS.LIB/%LIBL%.LIB/GETKURSJAV.PGM: Object does not exist.
>                   at com.ibm.as400.access.RemoteCommandImplRemote.runProgramOffThread(RemoteCommandImplRemote.java:595)
>                   at com.ibm.as400.access.RemoteCommandImplRemote.runProgram(RemoteCommandImplRemote.java:532)
>                   at com.ibm.as400.access.ProgramCall.run(ProgramCall.java:780)
>                   at com.ibm.as400.data.PcmlProgram.callProgram(PcmlProgram.java:681)
>                   at com.ibm.as400.data.PcmlDocument.callProgram(PcmlDocument.java:462)
>                   at com.ibm.as400.data.ProgramCallDocument.callProgram(ProgramCallDocument.java:445)
>                   ... 1 more

and this is my java code

```
import com.ibm.as400.access.AS400;
import com.ibm.as400.access.AS400Message;
import com.ibm.as400.access.ProgramParameter;
import com.ibm.as400.data.PcmlException;
import com.ibm.as400.data.ProgramCallDocument;

public class CallRPG {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AS400 as400 = null;

    String host = "10.2.62.7";
    String username = "USERNAME";
    String password = "PASSWORD";

    as400 = new AS400(host, username, password);

    if (as400 == null) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Connection Success");
    }
    ProgramCallDocument pcml;

    try {
        pcml = new ProgramCallDocument(as400, "getkursjav.pcml");
        pcml.setValue("GETKURSJAV.CCCKRS", "51");
        pcml.setValue("GETKURSJAV.IDXKRS", "5");

        // call the program
        boolean rc = pcml.callProgram("GETKURSJAV");
        if (rc == false) {
            System.out.println("Program failed");
        } else {

            int outputData = (int) pcml.getValue("GETKURSJAV.ZRTNKRS");
            System.out.println(outputData / 100000);            
        }
    } catch (PcmlException pe) {
        System.out.println(" Caught Exception ");
        pe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

}
```

and this is my pcml file

```
<pcml version="4.0">
   <program name="GETKURSJAV" path="/QSYS.LIB/%LIBL%.LIB/GETKURSJAV.PGM">
      <data name="CCCKRS" type="packed" length="2" precision="0" usage="input" />
      <data name="IDXKRS" type="packed" length="2" precision="0" usage="input" />
      <data name="ZRTNKRS" type="char" length="10" usage="output" />
   </program>
</pcml>
```

what's wrong with my code ?
Is I need to add as400 CURLIB and PRGLIB to my java code ? if yes, how can I add the libraries ?

Comment: Side note: `if (as400 == null) ` that's not possible because you did a `new`

Comment: This looks like a library list issue. Are you sure the program is in the job's library list?

Comment: Sure that %LIBL% is okay? (Not an AS/400 guy.) Looks like an env variable.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article, [Calling RPG on the AS400 from Java](https://bthurley.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/calling-rpg-on-the-as400-from-java/), %LIBL%.LIB is allowed...

But it's not shown specifically on the documentation for [PCML program tag](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/pcmlpgtg.htm)

This section of the docs, [Integrated file system path names for server objects](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzahh/ifspath.htm) has
[image]

I'd try using just
`path="/QSYS.LIB/%LIBL%/GETKURSJAV.PGM"`

Comment: hi, thanks for your help.
I've been change the path to `path="/QSYS.LIB/%LIBL%/GETKURSJAV.PGM"` the error has not shown, but now the result is blank.

Comment: outputdata is an INT in the java, yet a CHAR is returned from the RPG...perhaps that is part of your issue?

Comment: I've been change the output to CHAR, but the result still blank.

Comment: What should it return?  Are you sure the RPG program returns that?  Probably should post the RPG code in a separate question .

Comment: hi, the problem solved.
I've been add the `ADDLIBLE LIB` on my java code. thanks